# Two Web Deployment projects on single Web Application project -- how many compiles?

Tags: compilation, web-deployment-project, vs-web-application-project, assemblyversionattribute

I've got one Web Application project and two Web Deployment projects against that one Web Application project: WebApplication1, WebApplication1.csproj_deploy1, and WebApplication1.csproj_deploy2.

WebApplication1 uses the following assembly attribute, which bakes the date/time, down to the second, into the assembly at compile time:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.*")]

Will the two WebApplication1.dll files which are the output of the two web deployment projects have the same date/time baked into them, down to the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two WebApplication1.dll files which are the output of the two web deployment projects have the same date/time baked into them.